# How to change textbox value on key up in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox, keyup

I just want to change the VALUE attribute of textbox on key up. But when I am typing something the value remains same in the mark up. I want to change it in mark up too. Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FazilMir/h5tpk/4/) .

MARK UP

```
<input type="text" value="Type Your Name" id="textBox1" />
<span id="userName"></span>
```

jQuery

```
$("#textBox1").keyup(function () {

 $("#userName").text($(this).val());

});
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: your submited code working good for me! what is the problem!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add this line to your code:

```
    $("#textBox1").attr('value', $(this).val())
```

check your updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h5tpk/6/

Comment: @Vickel what is this line job in your answer!? `$("#textBox1").attr('value', $(this).val())`

Comment: @peimanF.: OP asked how to change value attribute of his textbox on a key up event. That's what this line of code does, have you checked the fiddle? Use your browser's console and check the html value of #textBox1...

Comment: yes , got the point , this was my misunderstanding because .val() can access the value and don't need to change `attr('value')`

Answer (score 0):

just wrap your code in

```
$(function(){

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h5tpk/5/

Comment: That doesn't change the value attribute of the input?

Comment: @Scott my code is working fine but i want to change the value attribute of TEXTBOX in MARK UP...

Comment: if I am using alert its giving the perfect value but what i want is that when I type something in textbox the VALUE Attribute of it should also get changed in mark up.

Answer (score 0):

You could also access the textbox via:

```
$("#textBox1").keyup(function () {
  $("#userName").text($('#textBox1').val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=kTauiAAFgR